# how to display a div with a specific class based on a checkbox event?

Tags: amp-html

I must to set up a product filtering using the amp format.
The goal is to allow the filtering of these products if the attribute is selected.
Every attributes are displayed on a sidebar.
Once the check box has been selected only the products related to the attribute must be displayed.

```
// Display checkboxes
<input
    checked
    class='filter-input' 
    style='width: 18%;'
    type='checkbox'
    role='checkbox'
    tabindex='-1' 
    value="<?php echo $value_finale_without_count; ?>" 
    on="change:AMP.setState({<?php echo $value_finale_without_count; ?>: 'hide'})">
                                     <label><?php echo $value_finale; ?></label>
</input>
```

Each div is initialized like this :

```
<div class="FilterOptions" [class]="(<?php echo $chaine_attribute; ?> || 'FilterOptions')" >
```

I know it's possible to use the functionality `"toogle.visibility"` but it seems to be used only in the case of an id and not class ...